# Is there away I can make this SQL statement to sort the month using year?

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql

I'm trying to get the total of users per `department, per year and per month,`

This is statement, it is working properly, I get the data I want but it's unorganized, is there anyway I can make it more organized?

```
SELECT
        u.department,
        YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y')) AS year,
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y'), '%b') AS month,
        COUNT(*) AS event_count
    FROM
        userlibrary tlc
    LEFT JOIN
        users u ON tlc.userfullname = u.fullname
    WHERE
        u.type = ?
        AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y')) BETWEEN ? AND ?
    GROUP BY
        u.department,
        year,
        month
    ORDER BY
        u.department,
        year,
        month;
  `;
  
  const [results, fields] = await connection.query(sql, [
    type,
    `${startYear}-${from}`,
    `${endYear}-${end}`,
  ]);
```

This is the result data I get, it's fine but seems more unstructured

```
[
    {
        "department": null,
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Aug",
        "event_count": 27
    },
    {
        "department": null,
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 4
    },
    {
        "department": null,
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Nov",
        "event_count": 29
    },
    {
        "department": null,
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Oct",
        "event_count": 49
    },
]
```

I get the data I want, but is it possible to

```
"null": {
        "2022": {
            "Aug": 27,
            "Dec": 4,
             etc...
        },
        "2023": {
            "Apr": 25,
            "Aug": 7,
            "Feb": 3,
             etc...


        }
    },
```

Comment: It is tagged under `javascript`. Is it related to it?

Comment: *This is the result data I get* Impossible. Your query produces a rowset whereas you provide one solid JSON array of objects. Or this is an output interpretation made by some software.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the JavaScript part.